# PHP / FPDF: How to insert image at cell?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I want to display image from MySQL to PDF using FPDF library. the image that i stored in MySQL is BLOB. I already success to display the image. The current code will be like this.

```
    $logo = $row['photo_before'];
    $pdf->MemImage(base64_decode($logo), 100, 50);
```

But, how I want to put the $logo to a cell? My current code for the cell as below:

```
    $pdf->Cell(95,50,'$logo',1,0, 'C');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `$logo`.

Comment: cannot, got error

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cell like:

```
//Cell
Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, 
boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
```

Then create image in same position:

```
//Image
 Image(string file [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, string type [, mixed 
 link]]]]]])
```

Or:

```
$image1 = "img/image1.jpg";
 $this->Cell( 40, 40, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78), 0, 0, 'L', false );
```

Edit you code:

```
$pdf->Cell(95,50,$pdf->MemImage(base64_decode($logo), 100, 50),1,0, 'C');
```

Comment: but I use MemImage library also

Comment: is same answer replace $pdf->image with code of Memimage

Comment: seriously i don't understand. Based on my code above, can you edit it?

Comment: still cannot, the image is follow the (100,50) coordinates